# Creating a map with values containing generics

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a map with a key being a single object and a value being many objects, some containing generics. Is there a concise way to do this in Kotlin? I've used data classes in the past, but haven't found a way to make that work with generics.

Thanks!

Edit: Here's an example:

```
class SomeClass<E> {
    data class Data(val str: String, val int: Int, val e: E) //the last value is invalid

    val map: MutableMap<String, Data> = mutableMapOf()

}
```

Comment: Could you please add a usage example? That would clarify the question.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like Guava's [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap). Is that right?

Comment: I've updated the post with an example. The Multimap is pretty close, but I would like to support multiple value types.

Comment: Your tastes are very... singular :D Are you sure, you need to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from your example, this should work for you.

```
data class Data<E>(val str: String, val int: Int, val e: E)

class SomeClass<E> {

    val map: MutableMap<String, Data<E>> = mutableMapOf()

}
```

I'm defining `Data` as an external, generic class, and use that inside the actual class.

Edit: Actually, you don't even need to move the data class outside of the outer class:

```
class SomeClass<E> {
    data class Data<T>(val str: String, val int: Int, val e: T)

    val map: MutableMap<String, Data<E>> = mutableMapOf()

}
```